# Role based access control for REST APIs

Tags: spring-boot, api-gateway

How do I do role validation for REST APIs?

I have 2 roles called `admin` and `manager`. How do I limit the access of REST APIs using RBAC (Role-based Access Control)? For example, `/users` POST can be accessed by `admin` role and  `/users` GET can be accessed by `manager` role.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using Spring Security.

## Spring Security

A highly customizable framework, Spring Security is widely used to handle the authentication and access control (authorization) issues arising in any Enterprise based application developed in Java.

Ex :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/user/login").permitAll().antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS)

                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/list").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
                .authenticated();       

    }   
}
```